# How to access elements inside MLMultiArray in CoreML

Tags: ios, objective-c, multidimensional-array, machine-learning, coreml

I have initialized `MLMultiArray` using `initWithDataPointer` as shown in the code below:

```
float count = 512 * 384;
  double *tempBuffer = malloc(count * sizeof(double));
  NSError *error = NULL;
  NSArray *shape = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:512],[NSNumber numberWithInt:384], nil];
  NSArray *stride = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], nil];

  MLMultiArray *mlMultiArray = [[MLMultiArray alloc] initWithDataPointer:tempBuffer
                                                                   shape:shape
                                                                dataType:MLMultiArrayDataTypeDouble
                                                                 strides:stride
                                                             deallocator:^(void * _Nonnull bytes) { free(bytes); }
                                                                   error:&error];
```

Based on the `MLMultiArray` documentation mentioned in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmultiarray), `subscript` needs to be used for accessing elements.

If I access the elements in the way shown, is it correct?

```
NSNumber *val = [mlMultiArray objectForKeyedSubscript:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], nil]];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you use `mlMultiArray.dataPointer`, cast it to `double *`, and then access the contents of the data buffer directly. You can compute where element `i, j, k` is using the strides:

```
double *ptr = (double *) mlMultiArray.dataPointer;
NSInteger offset = i*stride[0].intValue + j*stride[1].intValue + k*stride[2].intValue;
double val = ptr[offset];
```

Comment: Thanks, Even the one I have mentioned also works. Somehow I was giving wrong stride values